# Recursively escape Maze

Tags: c++, recursion

***Homework, I'm just asking if my logic is sound, and if not, what cases I am missing, not how to do it.***

I have an assignment where we had to create a randomly generated maze out of a data file given to us. Each room has is given a number between 1-100 and has (up to) 4 adjacent rooms: North, East, South, and West. A room without an adjacent room will have an adjacent room with a negative identifier. Our "person" is randomly dropped into one of these rooms, and we must find the path out. Outside is designated by a room number of 0.

I have everything but the recursion done, which is almost done. This is my solution:

```
void Graph::findPath( Room * curRoom )
{
    if( curRoom -> myNumber == 0 )
    //Escaped!
    else
    {
       if( curRoom -> North -> visited == false )
    {   
        curRoom -> visited == true;
        findPath( curRoom -> North )
    }

    if( curRoom -> East -> visited == false )
    {   
        curRoom -> visited == true;
        findPath( curRoom -> East )
    }
    if( curRoom -> South -> visited == false )
    {   
        curRoom -> visited == true;
        findPath( curRoom -> South )
    }
    if( curRoom -> West -> visited == false )
    {   
        curRoom -> visited == true;
        findPath( curRoom -> West )
    }
    }
```

}

I think I have it correctly. My only concern is that we need to print out the correct path, which I know can be done, but I have no idea how to do it without printing incorrect ones too.

Thank you for your time.

If any information is missing, let me know and I will reply post-haste.

Comment: Currently you aren't printing anything, plus your if should be changed such as an else is not needed at all.

Comment: The if is needed, because the outside is a room not pointing to anything with it's NSEW pointers, and I don't want to access bad memory. But I didn't share that information, sorry.

Comment: So what if you were to write if( curRoom -> myNumber != 0 ) {...} without the else?

Comment: Unless I added a break in the {...}, it would still attempt every if case.

Comment: You are using `==` in `curRoom -> visited == false;` and this is a test for equality, not an assignment (you should use `=`).  Also, idiomatically it is not necessary to write `if (condition == true)` or `if (condition == false)`, you can just say `if (condition)` or `if (!condition)`, and I personally prefer `if (not condition)` for readability though I'm probably in the minority for that.  I'd also say that your spacing conventions (while not invalid) are strange and they consume a lot of space...your code would "fit in" better if you wrote it like `if (curRoom->West->visited)`.

Comment: @HostileFork haha thanks, just a typo!
As for my spacing conventions, I like more whitespace than most -- it makes reading it easier for me.

Comment: @Joshua Compile and test what code you have before posting, if you can.  (Enable all warnings with -Wall too.)  As for spacing: what constitutes good and bad style in formatting can indeed be contentious, but the spacing convention you are using is not one of those contentions.  It's "bad" enough that no professional C++ programmers would adopt it.  If you're only programming for yourself, then okay.  But if you ever show code to others, I think it's valuable to at least *be aware* of what comes off as amateur or unprofessional, "sending a message" that you don't know what you're doing!  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have the `findPath()` function return an indication of whether it found a path out of the room rather than always trying all four paths out of the room.  (If you find a way out to the North, you don't need to check whether there's also a way out going East, or West, or South.)

You should probably add a room to a list (stack) of 'places on the path' before recursing, removing it before returning if there is no path out from this room.  When you get out, this list tells you the path you took.

Comment: Haha I figured out something similar a couple of minutes ago. I'll be posting my solution once I finish writing it.